# Launch activity timeout because the activity starts another one

Tags: android, android-espresso

My activity 'MainActivity' needs to start another activity ontop of itself, under some conditions.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    if (condition) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class))
    }
}
```

I want to run a test on MainActivity, asseting that AnotherActivity in started with those conditions.

My Espresso test fail launching MainActivity because it seems to wait MainActivity to appear on Screen. This won't happen since I'm starting the other activity. The activity is launched via ActivityTestRule.

I got the following exception when running my Espresso test:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.djoglobal.corebelt.debug/com.djo.compex.corebelt.ui.MainActivity } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1488804986217 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1488804986217. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:360)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:219)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:268)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at tools.fastlane.screengrab.locale.LocaleTestRule$1.evaluate(LocaleTestRule.java:32)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
```

I have the same behaviour if I start 'AnotherActivity' in onResume.

I'm using Espresso 2.2.1

Any idea to test this scenario ?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can post starting the activity to `Handler` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    if (condition) {
        final int millisUntilLaunch = 500;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class));
            }
        }, millisUntilLaunch);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working thank you. But I would prefer: 1) Not to modify app functionnality / production code to make test working. 2) Not let the user see a small apparition of the MainActivity in between

Answer (score 0):

I have utilised [Espresso Intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/) to stub an intent of the started activity to prevent it from being displayed.

In my case LoginActivity is started in onCreate() of MainActivity if a user isn't logged in:

```
Account account = AccountUtils.getAccount(this);
if (account == null) {
    startActivity(this, LoginActivity.class);
    finish();
    return;
}
```

The Espresso test which validates that LoginActivity is started:

```
@Test
public void startsLoginActivityImmediately() {
    Intents.init();

    // Stub the login intent to prevent LoginActivity from being displayed.
    // This helps to fix the Espresso timeout exception.
    Matcher<Intent> loginIntent = hasComponent(LoginActivity.class.getName());
    intending(loginIntent).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(0, null));

    mActivityRule.launchActivity(null);
    intended(hasComponent(LoginActivity.class.getName()));

    Intents.release();
}
```

I hope this approach solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem somewhere here:

`mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null);`

When I pass `null`, I have same error as you.

This is my code example and it works in every scenario (see commented out parts):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<TestActivity1> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TestActivity1.class);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Intents.init();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        Intents.release();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);
        intended(hasComponent(TestActivity2.class.getName()));
    }
}
```

....

```
public class TestActivity1 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        setTitle("first");

        if (isConditionMatch()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, TestActivity2.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can try implement unit tests here by replacing `startActivity(new Intent(this, TestActivity2.class));` with method call and put this into presenter or something like this.